# Creating a UI with Tkinter. When trying to adjust the font of my button text and I run the program, I get this error back

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

This is the code I have written so far...

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("400x400")
app.configure(bg='gray')


photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\ex\ex_button_active.png")
myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')

tk.Label(app, text='ex', bg='gray', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\ex\ex_icon.ico')

ex_activation_button = tk.Button(app,
                                    bg='black',
                                    image=photo,
                                    width=100,
                                    height=100)
ex_stop_button = tk.Button(app,
                              bg='Gray',
                              text='Stop',
                              width=15,
                              height=5)
tk.Button['font'] = myFont

app.title("ex")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ex_stop_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

app.mainloop()
```

I get this error back...

```
tk.Button['font'] = myFont
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Its really a simple font change for the text on the button. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ex_stop_button['font'] = myFont`?

Comment: Dang! That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tk.Button` is a *type*, like `int` or `float` etc. You would get exactly the same error if you did `int['font'] = myFont`.

Instead, what you want to do is set the font on an *instance* of `tk.Button`. In your case that would be `ex_stop_button`:

```
ex_stop_button['font'] = myFont
```

-or-

```
ex_stop_button = tk.Button(app,
                           bg='Gray',
                           text='Stop',
                           width=15,
                           height=5,
                           font=myFont)
```